# Extract all strings between two strings

Tags: c#

I'm trying to develop a method that will match all strings between two strings:

I've tried this but it returns only the first match:

```
string ExtractString(string s, string start,string end)
        {
            // You should check for errors in real-world code, omitted for brevity

            int startIndex = s.IndexOf(start) + start.Length;
            int endIndex = s.IndexOf(end, startIndex);
            return s.Substring(startIndex, endIndex - startIndex);
        }
```

Let's suppose we have this string

```
String Text = "A1FIRSTSTRINGA2A1SECONDSTRINGA2akslakhflkshdflhksdfA1THIRDSTRINGA2"
```

I would like a c# function doing the following :

```
public List<string> ExtractFromString(String Text,String Start, String End)
{
    List<string> Matched = new List<string>();
    .
    .
    .
    return Matched; 
}
// Example of use 

ExtractFromString("A1FIRSTSTRINGA2A1SECONDSTRINGA2akslakhflkshdflhksdfA1THIRDSTRINGA2","A1","A2")

    // Will return :
    // FIRSTSTRING
    // SECONDSTRING
    // THIRDSTRING
```

Thank you for your help !

Comment: How do you identify your "values"?

Comment: Sorry I was not too Clear ! The idea is that all the strings Between the String "A1" and the String "A2" will be returned !

Comment: try using regular expressions, will work perfectly for this :)

Comment: See the Update ! I tried The Substring but the Index of return Only the first on. I need to return all of them; I'm still trying will let you know if any update ! :) Thanks for your help !

Answer (score 35, accepted):

```
    private static List<string> ExtractFromBody(string body, string start, string end)
    {
        List<string> matched = new List<string>();

        int indexStart = 0;
        int indexEnd = 0;

        bool exit = false;
        while (!exit)
        {
            indexStart = body.IndexOf(start);

            if (indexStart != -1)
            {
                indexEnd = indexStart + body.Substring(indexStart).IndexOf(end);

                matched.Add(body.Substring(indexStart + start.Length, indexEnd - indexStart - start.Length));

                body = body.Substring(indexEnd + end.Length);
            }
            else
            {
                exit = true;
            }
        }

        return matched;
    }
```

Comment: this code throw exception if endString is before startString like \r\n you must take indexEnd after indexStart

Answer (score 17):

Here is a solution using RegEx.  Don't forget to include the following using statement.

`using System.Text.RegularExpressions`

It will correctly return only text between the start and end strings given.

**Will not be returned:**

```
akslakhflkshdflhksdf
```

**Will be returned:**

```
FIRSTSTRING
SECONDSTRING
THIRDSTRING
```

It uses the regular expression pattern `[start string].+?[end string]`

The start and end strings are escaped in case they contain regular expression special characters.

```
    private static List<string> ExtractFromString(string source, string start, string end)
    {
        var results = new List<string>();

        string pattern = string.Format(
            "{0}({1}){2}", 
            Regex.Escape(start), 
            ".+?", 
             Regex.Escape(end));

        foreach (Match m in Regex.Matches(source, pattern))
        {
            results.Add(m.Groups[1].Value);
        }

        return results;
    }
```

You could make that into an extension method of String like this:

```
public static class StringExtensionMethods
{
    public static List<string> EverythingBetween(this string source, string start, string end)
    {
        var results = new List<string>();

        string pattern = string.Format(
            "{0}({1}){2}",
            Regex.Escape(start),
            ".+?",
             Regex.Escape(end));

        foreach (Match m in Regex.Matches(source, pattern))
        {
            results.Add(m.Groups[1].Value);
        }

        return results;
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
string source = "A1FIRSTSTRINGA2A1SECONDSTRINGA2akslakhflkshdflhksdfA1THIRDSTRINGA2";
string start = "A1";
string end = "A2";

List<string> results = source.EverythingBetween(start, end);
```

Comment: If you add perenthesis `"{0}({1}){2}"` in the pattern you could use `Match.Groups[1]` to get the value

Comment: Thanks for this answer! I had to use "foreach (Match m ..." (instead of var m) for it to work, it otherwise through an error.

Answer (score 4):

```
text.Split(new[] {"A1", "A2"}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
```

Answer (score 2):

You can split the string into an array using the start identifier in following code:

```
String str = "A1FIRSTSTRINGA2A1SECONDSTRINGA2akslakhflkshdflhksdfA1THIRDSTRINGA2";

String[] arr = str.Split("A1");
```

Then iterate through your array and remove the last 2 characters of each string (to remove the A2). You'll also need to discard the first array element as it will be empty assuming the string starts with A1.

Code is untested, currently on a mobile

Comment: Good Idea ! I will try and let you know the result ! :)

Answer (score 0):

**This is a generic solution**, and I believe more readable code. Not tested, so beware.

```
public static IEnumerable<IList<T>> SplitBy<T>(this IEnumerable<T> source, 
                                               Func<T, bool> startPredicate,
                                               Func<T, bool> endPredicate, 
                                               bool includeDelimiter)
{
    var l = new List<T>();
    foreach (var s in source)
    {
        if (startPredicate(s))
        {
            if (l.Any())
            {
                l = new List<T>();
            }
            l.Add(s);
        }
        else if (l.Any())
        {
            l.Add(s);
        }

        if (endPredicate(s))
        {
            if (includeDelimiter)
                yield return l;
            else
                yield return l.GetRange(1, l.Count - 2);

            l = new List<T>();
        }
    }
}
```

In your case you can call,

```
var text = "A1FIRSTSTRINGA2A1SECONDSTRINGA2akslakhflkshdflhksdfA1THIRDSTRINGA2";
var splits = text.SplitBy(x => x == "A1", x => x == "A2", false);
```

This is not the most efficient when you do not want the delimiter to be included (like your case) in result but efficient for opposite cases. To speed up your case one can directly call the GetEnumerator and make use of MoveNext.