# How to get a word in string C#

Tags: c#, string

Given :

```
string command = "<CP1><SSA1>";
string command_2 = "<CP1><MPS>";
```

How can I get the word "CP1" and "1" from 'SSA1' in command and for command_2 is "CP1" and "MPS" then set to another variables?

I already search the similar question but still not found the best answer.

### Edited :

For command variable, I want get 'CP1' from CP1 and '1' from SSA1. And for command_2 variable I want get 'CP1' from CP1 and 'MPS' from MPS.

Comment: in **command** what you want?? CP1 and 1?? which 1 it is?? 1 from SSA1 or from CP1?? you need to make it more clear

Comment: Sorry about that, the '1' is from SSA

Comment: sorry to say but you have no similarity in command and command_2 desired output.. in command you want last digit?? and in command_2 you want whole word? is it so?? you need to make it clear.. your requirement is not clear still..

Comment: dear please edit your question to make things clear.

Comment: @DeepakSharma Yes that I looking for

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to get strings between angled brackets.. then you just replace `"SSA"` with `""` and you have all the words you wanted !!!

```
using System.IO;
using System;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;
using System.Collections.Generic;

class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {
        string command = "<CP1><SSA1>";
        string command_2 = "<CP1><MPS>";

        prnt(command);
        prnt(command_2);
            //prnt(command+command_2); //even this will work :)
    }

    private static void prnt(string str)
    {
                List<string> l = ExtractFromString(str,"<",">");
        foreach(string ll in l)
            Console.WriteLine(ll.Replace("SSA",""));
    }

    private static List<string> ExtractFromString(string text, string start, string end)
    {            
        List<string> Matched = new List<string>();
        int index_start = 0, index_end=0;
        bool exit = false;
        while(!exit)
        {
            index_start = text.IndexOf(start);
            index_end = text.IndexOf(end);
            if (index_start != -1 && index_end != -1)
            {
                Matched.Add(text.Substring(index_start + start.Length, index_end - index_start - start.Length));
                text = text.Substring(index_end + end.Length);
            }
            else
                exit = true;
        }
        return Matched;
    }
}
```

### Output:

```
CP1
1
CP1
MPS
```

Source of Extract method: [Extract all strings between two strings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13780654/extract-all-strings-between-two-strings)

Answer (score 0):

You're parsing XML, use XElement classes instead. Then use String or Regex classes to parse tag string content.

Comment: I don't see any xml, other than `<` and `>`s

Answer (score 0):

this is the code:

```
string s1 = "<CP1><SSA1>";

int start = s1.IndexOf("<CP");
int end = s1.IndexOf(">"); string
numString = s1.Substring(start + 3, end-start-3);  // get the 1

start = s1.IndexOf("<SSA");
end = s1.Length-1;
numString = s1.Substring(start + 4, end - start - 4);         // get the 1
```

with this code you should receive the numbers after your token, it's doesn't matter how much digits it contain.

- To convert the string to int use Parse function, like this: `int.Parse(numString)`
- Same answer to the second string

Answer (score 0):

@Chuki2

I dont know what exactly you want to achieve.. but it could be a way to do this.. check it out below..!!

```
string command = "<CP1><SSA1>";
string command_2 = "<CP1><MPS>";

command = command.Replace("<", "#").Replace(">", "#");

command_2 = command_2.Replace("<", "#").Replace(">", "#");

string[] val = command.Split(
                  new char[]{'#'},
                  StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries
               );

string[] val_2 = command_2.Split(
                  new char[] { '#' },
                  StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries
               );

//now because you want to get the only "1" from "SSA1"
//well i dont know what really you want to do but it could be one way to do this.

string lastParameter = val[val.Length-1];
val[val.Length - 1] = lastParameter.Substring(lastParameter.Length - 1);
```

Answer (score 0):

Another way:

```
string[] parts = command.Split(new char[] {'<', '>'},StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
string part1 = parts[0];
string part2 = parts[1].StartsWith("SSA") : parts[1].Substring(3) : parts[1];
```