# Extract all .jpg File Name strings in List from string in c#

Tags: c#, .net, regex

I have following big string and I want all .jpg file name with extension in to string List in C# but I don't know how to get it.

```
[{\"url\":\"https:\\/\\/\\/data\\/menus\\/799\\/799\\/dd2d49c78b1fe3a9cea5761d90132ff1.jpg\",\"href\":\"https:\\/\\/\\/data\\/menus\\/799\\/799\\/dd2d49c78b1fe3a9cea5761d90132ff1.jpg\",\"filename\":\"dd2d49c78b1fe3a9cea5761d90132ff1.jpg\",\"url_master\":\"menus_original\\/799\\/799\\/dd2d49c78b1fe3a9cea5761d90132ff1.jpg\",\"path_master\":\"\\/home\\/foodie\\/zomato_data\\/menus_original\\/799\\/799\\/dd2d49c78b1fe3a9cea5761d90132ff1.jpg\",\"data_center\":\"\",\"menu_type\":\"FOOD\",\"title\":\"FOOD\",\"menu_type_class\":\"FOOD\",\"real_menu_type\":\"FOOD\",\"is_salt_special_menu\":0,\"start_date\":\"\",\"consumer_upload\":0,\"start_date_formatted\":\"\",\"end_date\":\"\",\"end_date_formatted\":\"\",\"id\":131698200},{\"url\":\"https:\\/\\/\\/data\\/menus\\/799\\/799\\/f9f923c43b6b2d2a87ad8ce22b9995da.jpg\",\"href\":\"https:\\/\\/\\/data\\/menus\\/799\\/799\\/f9f923c43b6b2d2a87ad8ce22b9995da.jpg\",\"filename\":\"f9f923c43b6b2d2a87ad8ce22b9995da.jpg\",\"url_master\":\"menus_original\\/799\\/799\\/f9f923c43b6b2d2a87ad8ce22b9995da.jpg\",\"path_master\":\"\\/home\\/foodie\\/zomato_data\\/menus_original\\/799\\/799\\/f9f923c43b6b2d2a87ad8ce22b9995da.jpg\",\"data_center\":\"\",\"menu_type\":\"FOOD\",\"title\":\"FOOD\",\"menu_type_class\":\"FOOD\",\"real_menu_type\":\"FOOD\",\"is_salt_special_menu\":0,\"start_date\":\"\",\"consumer_upload\":0,\"start_date_formatted\":\"\",\"end_date\":\"\",\"end_date_formatted\":\"\",\"id\":131698203},{\"url\":\"https:\\/\\/\\/data\\/menus\\/799\\/799\\/ea3117de65882f14723480841940b5b1.jpg\",\"href\":\"https:\\/\\/\\/data\\/menus\\/799\\/799\\/ea3117de65882f14723480841940b5b1.jpg\",\"filename\":\"ea3117de65882f14723480841940b5b1.jpg\",\"url_master\":\"menus_original\\/799\\/799\\/ea3117de65882f14723480841940b5b1.jpg\",\"path_master\":\"\\/home\\/foodie\\/zomato_data\\/menus_original\\/799\\/799\\/ea3117de65882f14723480841940b5b1.jpg\",\"data_center\":\"\",\"menu_type\":\"FOOD\",\"title\":\"FOOD\",\"menu_type_class\":\"FOOD\",\"real_menu_type\":\"FOOD\",\"is_salt_special_menu\":0,\"start_date\":\"\",\"consumer_upload\":0,\"start_date_formatted\":\"\",\"end_date\":\"\",\"end_date_formatted\":\"\",\"id\":131698204}]
```

**I want below list from sting :**

```
dd2d49c78b1fe3a9cea5761d90132ff1.jpg
dd2d49c78b1fe3a9cea5761d90132ff1.jpg
dd2d49c78b1fe3a9cea5761d90132ff1.jpg
f9f923c43b6b2d2a87ad8ce22b9995da.jpg
f9f923c43b6b2d2a87ad8ce22b9995da.jpg
```

Thank You... in advance

Comment: What have u tried so far??

Comment: I have tried from this : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13780654/extract-all-strings-between-two-strings

Comment: Is the string in a format like json or something ?

Comment: No, this string is not in Json format It's only in string format @RishabhKumar

Comment: Can you show us part of the big string that you have as an example?

Comment: please see edited question for output which i want from big string @Ibrahim

Comment: This looks to me like a Json string with escaped characters... does the string actually contain sequences like `\"`, or is it just the debugger display?

Comment: Yes, string contain sequences like \" @vesan

Comment: Where do you get this string from? An api call? This surely does look like a valid json, and it parses correctly.

Comment: Hey @RAJNIKPATEL did u tried my solution. :) Give it a try. U might like it.

Comment: @MohitShrivastava Mr. Ibrahim's code working well and using that code solved my problem. So, I haven't tried any more code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you just need .jpg file name, you can try this simple Regex:

```
\w+\.jpg
```

Demo: https://regex101.com/r/KMWtZY/1

You can use it with C# as follows:

```
var regex = new Regex(@"\w+\.jpg");
return regex.Matches(strInput);
```

Source: [1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4740984/c-sharp-regex-matches-example)

Comment: Yes, I want this but how i can use in c# ?

Comment: You should escape "." character. Your regex also matches 2ff1_jpg, asdasd,jpg

Comment: @RenatZamaletdinov Thanks, I updated my answer and escaped "."

Answer (score 0):

Your string seems like it is a JSON String. and thus it would be easier and convienent approach to desealize the JSON into an object and fetch the values like

Create a class for the Object of your JSON String

```
public class YourData
{
    public string url { get; set; }
    public string href { get; set; }
    public string filename { get; set; }
    public string url_master { get; set; }
    public string path_master { get; set; }
    public string data_center { get; set; }
    public string menu_type { get; set; }
    public string title { get; set; }
    public string menu_type_class { get; set; }
    public string real_menu_type { get; set; }
    public int is_salt_special_menu { get; set; }
    public string start_date { get; set; }
    public int consumer_upload { get; set; }
    public string start_date_formatted { get; set; }
    public string end_date { get; set; }
    public string end_date_formatted { get; set; }
    public int id { get; set; }
}
```

Than

```
//From wherever you are reading it.
string jsonstr = "Your Json String";
//I Removed all the / and \ from the string
jsonstr = jsonstr.Replace("/", "");
jsonstr = jsonstr.Replace("\\", "");
//at last of the string you have something like this 
//;\n        .menuTypes = [\"DEFAULT\",\"FOOD\",\"BAR\",\"DELIVERY\",\"SPECIAL\",\"TAKEAWAY\",\"INTERNAL\"];\n
//which is not the part of the JSON string. So I removed that part as well to make it a valid JSON
jsonstr = jsonstr.Remove(jsonstr.IndexOf(";n"));
//Console.WriteLine(jsonstr); //You can uncomment it to see how JSON looks after cleaning.
//Just Deserialize the JSON
List<YourData> yd = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<YourData>>(jsonstr);
//Loop to get all the filenames or any other fields you want 
foreach(YourData ydd in yd)
{
    Console.WriteLine(ydd.filename);
}
```

Comment: Hey!! Angry downvoter. Please specify the reason for a downvote.