# C#: How To Filter String In XML format

Tags: c#, html, xml

I have a field which allows html format to be stored in my database.

```
public class MyItem {
    ....
    [AllowHtml]
    public string Description { get; set; }
    ....
}
```

Somehow I want to display a list of my items but only show the first 500 characters.

```
Description = new string(v.EventDescription.Take(500).ToArray()) + "...";
```

I realize I take everything from it including all xml tags like `p, img, h3, etc`. How can I filter only to take the content inside `p` (paragraph) only?

This is my html result:

```
<p style="text-align: center;">
    <img alt="" height="1200" src="/Content/Images/ContentImage/3a173930-d7ea-e711-a636-1c4d70ad76a8/wedding2.jpeg" width="1200"/>
</p>
<p>
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed varius est nisl, id ultrices purus posuere in. Nullam non elit faucibus, tempus orci id, convallis mi. Maecenas eget libero tortor. Proin dapibus massa quis erat condimentum, ut mollis sapien fringilla. Phasellus vitae porttitor nunc, sed laoreet lacus. Quisque convallis ...
    <span style="font-weight: bold;">Read more.</span>
</p>
```

Note: I need to do it from the server side not from the client side.

Comment: How did you obtain `EventDescription`from the xml? Using an html-parser will let you extract only the actual *value*  for the property, not it´s xml-representation.

Comment: And what have you tried? Use a HTML parser like HtmlAgilityPack and use the InnerText property. And I love people doing everything with LINQ. Much better than `.Substring()`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Extract all strings between two strings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13780654/extract-all-strings-between-two-strings)

Comment: @styx That duplicate is a really bad one as it suggests to use substringing or something similar in order to parse HTML, which is fundamently whrong.

Answer (score 0):

I do not suggest using string manipulators to achieve this, 
In this case i prefer using HtmlAgilityPack to parse the data, but validating your html is necessary. 
something like this.

```
descHtml = new string(v.EventDescription.ToArray());

if(validate(descHtml)){

  HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument htmlDocument = new 
  HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument();
  htmlDocument.LoadHtml(descHtml );
  var description = string.Join("{SEPARATOR}", 
  htmlDocument.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("/p/text()").Select(p => p.InnerText)); }
```